# MultiLanguage PHP Link

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I am with a little issue. Everything in this code is working but when someone put the link like this **?lang=enASa** instead of **?lang=en** for some reason it just shows the "define" (Don't know if I can call that a define) Example: Instead of showing: **Title** it shows this: **_TITLE** . The code is this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Set Language variable
    if(isset($_GET['lang']) && !empty($_GET['lang'])){
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];

        if(isset($_SESSION['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] != $_GET['lang']){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> location.reload(); </script>";
        }
    }

    // Include Language file
    if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
        include "lang_".$_SESSION['lang'].".php";
    }else{
        include "lang_en.php";
    }
?>
```

In the pages I am using this (`<?= _TITLE ?>`) to replace the words:

```
<h3 style="color: white" class="subheading left"><?= _TITLE ?></h3>
```

And to translate i am using this file (lang_en.php):

```
<?php

define("_TITLE", "Title");
```

All code works fine, and I was hoping that someone could help me here forcing to use default English when the lang is not valid. Example: If anyone tries `www.example.com/index.php?lang=edadsa` instead of `www.example.com/index.php?lang=en` our just `www.example.com/index.php` force to use the default.

Comment: Don't you get a warning saying that it can't include the file `lang_enASa.php` or don't you have error_reporting and display errors turned on?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson No

Comment: Then I would recommend that you read this post: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). That's pretty crucial when it comes to debugging. What actually happened was that the constant `_TITLE` wasn't defined (since it couldn't load the file that defines it), so PHP assumed that you meant to use `'_TITLE'` (a string) and echoed that for you.

Comment: Your code is awfully insecure

Comment: @user70960 how can I make it more secure?

Comment: @Peter You should not access GET directly, use [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) instead to sanitize the string and then verify, if that language is allowed (language file exists or is in the language list somewhere) for example.

Comment: Could you tell what I need exactly to replace? I don't want to do the wrong things

Answer (score 3):

You have to check if a language file exists for the given language, before calling the include.

```
// Include Language file
if(isset($_SESSION['lang']) && file_exists("lang_".$_SESSION['lang'].".php")){
 include "lang_".$_SESSION['lang'].".php";
}else{
 include "lang_en.php";
}
```

Comment: Thank u ;) It Worked